# Application that won't pin to the Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Kind of stumped - I have an application I've built (it's an old Visual FoxPro app) that won't pin to the Windows 7 task bar. Before you jump and say - FOXPRO is at fault - I have several other FoxPro apps running the same exact environment and they pin to the taskbar just fine. VFP 9 apps are EXEs with a runtime dependency but otherwise act like any other Windows exe.

I duplicated the behavior on another machine as well with a full installation package, but the app just will not pin.

I'm stumped and have no idea what could be the problem.

A couple of things i've tried that didn't work:

- Remove the icon from the EXE in case
  there's some Windows Icon convention
  problems
- Remove manifest and config files use
  with app
- Ran from shortcut - ran from EXE
  directly

Comment: I think, this belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/32765.aspx

Here's the blog post your wrote about this shortly after you asked this question. I thought I'd post it in case others are having the same problem. Unfortunately there must be other reasons this can happen because I'm having issues with pinning notes.exe to the taskbar and looking around the net, others are too.